# Difference between converting List to Array

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

I was just wondering what is the difference between following two approach of converting List to Array.

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
test.add("AB");
test.add("BC");
test.add("CD");
test.add("DE");
test.add("EF");

String[] testarray = test.toArray(new String[0]); // passing 0 as Array size
```

And below one :

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
test.add("AB");
test.add("BC");
test.add("CD");
test.add("DE");
test.add("EF");

String[] testarray = test.toArray(new String[test.size()]); // passing list's size
```

I got the same output for testarray on console.

Comment: Which java version are you using?

Comment: This is what the docs for JDK7 have to say about this: **toArray(T[] a)
Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper sequence (from first to last element); the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array.**

Comment: Performance wise the second method will be slower you are pre-allocating memory

Comment: Link to documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray()

Comment: @VigneshKalai will it not be re-used?

Comment: @NiklasR Also from documentation: ' If the list fits in the specified array, it is returned therein. Otherwise, a new array is allocated with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of this list.'

Comment: @NiklasR Java is called robust because it reuses

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280631/pass-zero-sized-array-save-allocation

Comment: @VigneshKalai the first one will actually be marginally slower, since you create a useless empty array and force toList() to create a second one of the right size.

Comment: @JBNizet now it's make more sense in terms of performance..!!

Comment: @JBNizet - If the size of the array being passed is sufficiently large (to hold elements of list), then the first one will be *marginally faster* :P

Comment: @JBNizet That's what I thought too, until I tested it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29444594/829571

Comment: @assylias I think we can all agree that if the goal is to have a new array and not to overwrite an existing array, both are equivalent and the difference in performance is so negligible that it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @assylias - The code actually suggests otherwise. If the size of array is `0`, then `Arrays.copyOf` is called. Whereas if the size of array is large enough to hold all elements of list, then `System.arraycopy` is called. Internally, `Arrays.copyOf` also calls `System.arraycopy` after executing some *rather complex* instruction(s).

Comment: @TheLostMind Arrays#copyOf is intrinsic in hotspot so that code is not really run (so is System.arraycopy) - see line 748 of [this file](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/classfile/vmSymbols.hpp#l748).

Comment: @assylias - Oh. So the code is optimized by the hotspot.. Thanks :)

Comment: @JBNizet yes you are right

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
```

a - This is the array into which the elements of the list are to be stored, if it is big enough; otherwise, a new array of the same runtime type is allocated for this purpose. So in first case a new array is being created while in second case, it is using the same array.

> Sample Code :

**Case -1 : array being passed can hold elements of list**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
        test.add("AB");
        test.add("BC");
        test.add("CD");
        test.add("DE");
        test.add("EF");
        String[] s= new String[10];
        String[] testarray = test.toArray(s); 
        System.out.println(s==testarray);
    }

O/P :

true
```

**Case-2 : Array being passed cannot hold elements of list**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
        test.add("AB");
        test.add("BC");
        test.add("CD");
        test.add("DE");
        test.add("EF");
        String[] s= new String[0];
        String[] testarray = test.toArray(s); 
        System.out.println(s==testarray);

    }

O/P :

false
```

Comment: @TheLostMind - Now, it's pretty clear from the code snippet...!! Thanks

Comment: additional 1 for improving my answer :)